# How to filter JS:ScriptIP-INF (TRJ) in BBClone Webstatistic

Tags: anti-virus, javascript, useragent, statistics

I`m using the webstatistic bbclone on my server.
In the last month my virus scanner sometimes blocks the details page.

it displays the detection of

> JS:ScriptIP-INF (TRJ)

on my bblone. But I compared all files bitwise with the original install files from the main page, they are identical.

I figured out, the the virus message disappaers if some more visits are listed in the statistic.

So I think somebody visits my website and sends a user-agent String with something virus like (e.g. javascript code).

I would to modify my bbclone to filter out these virus user-agent.

but I need to know how I can detect a visitor with this 
`JS:ScriptIP-INF (TRJ)` - user-agent.

I was searching in google and several forums for a answer, but I find no usefull information how to avoid this virus.

e.g. this: [My website is infected with JS:ScriptIP-inf [Trj]](https://serverfault.com/questions/138083/my-website-is-infected-with-jsscriptip-inf-trj)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  It's not the User Agent, it's the HTTP Referer.

I thought malware bots were visiting my website with a HTTP Referer with some malicious JS code injected in it.  So I changed BBClone's configuration not to display the HTTP Referer in the detailed stats, and it worked.

Edit your `conf/config.php` and make sure `$BBC_DETAILED_STAT_FIELDS` does not contain the variable `referer`, e.g.

```
$BBC_DETAILED_STAT_FIELDS = "id, time, ext, dns, ip, visits, os, browser, page, search";
```

I still don't know what is the offending referer string, though.  I'll dig into the raw logs and when I find something interesting I'll edit this answer.  Then we can filter out the string and have the referer data shown back in the detailed stats.

Comment: Your tipp sounds good, thank you.
I will check this when I get the next "detection" alert.

When your tipp solves the problem, I give you the "accepted answer" vote.

Comment: The alert shows up and then disappears as the old entries (containing the offending string) are deleted in the detailed log file.  To keep them for a longer time you can set the history to 500 i.e. the max recommended value.